# URL Rewrite for Custom WordPress page with multiple url parameters

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My WordPress site has a url that looks like this

https://example.com/coupon/?drug=PHENTERMINE&ndc=10702002501&quantity=15&zipCode=12084&radius=10

but it needs to look like this

https://example.com/coupon/phentermine

I'm not sure how WordPress permalinks play into .htaccess in that environment, but wonder if that's part of my issue?

The URL parameters are necessary to pull the correct data from an API. The site also uses CPT-UI and Advanced Custom Fields but I don't think that matters for this question.

So far, my htaccess code looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^\/coupon\/\?drug=([A-Z]+)\&ndc=[0-9]+\&quantity=[0-9]+\&zipCode=[0-9]&radius=[0-9]$   \/coupon\/$1  [NC,L]
```

But per https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ I get "the rule is not met".

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please do confirm if you are hitting link `https://example.com/coupon/?drug=PHENTERMINE&ndc=10702002501&quantity=15&zipCode=12084&radius=10` in browser and want it to redirect to `https://example.com/coupon/phentermine`?

Comment: Also in backend how the query string url is being served? From which basically?

Comment: Hi Ravinder. Yes, that is the link structure. It comes from a custom search feature that pulls the minimal information from a custom post type (CPT-UI and ACF) and builds the link. When the user clicks on it it sends the data via REST API. Then on that /coupon page there is another form in case the user wants to change any of the inputs and resubmit.  Thanks!

Comment: is that just one page? does it have a page template? maybe you don't have to load that rule across all pages and just redirect with a simple js / php code

Comment: Hi Sagive. I am open to options, but it is not just one page. There are about 6,000.

Comment: well.. i can grab that var using php, if it exists redirect to a new URL with that param. that's good?  drug name match the URL final path right? you need to embed that inside your header.php / page.php according to the structure. Wait.. let me thing about  a RewriteRule - we can always reutnr to that

Comment: i think we can init that query check - i haven't tried it - but it should work. its before the template itself. its hard for me to test, but let me write something and you can try it

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, i cannot test this simply at this time, but this should work. it is conditional which means you can extend it and add more conditions / other URL parameters. Hope this helps.

You can embed this in your theme functions.php file or any other
PHP file included into your functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'tampa_coupon_redirect');
function tampa_coupon_redirect() {
    if (!empty(get_query_var('coupon'))) {
        wp_redirect( site_url('/coupon/').get_query_var('coupon') );
        exit; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sagive. Where or how do I call this function?

Comment: you dont need to call it, it runs on its own during Wordpress "load" procedure... You see that line": add_action( 'init', 'tampa_coupon_redirect'); - this mean, when were in the "init step" of the load procedure, run "tampa_coupon_redirect" -

 init is a good moment in time because its before the page is actually loaded but we do have access to the URL parameters

Comment: You need to place it inside a file like functions.php or a file that is included into your functions.php file.